# @ symbol conflicts with IntelliJ shortcut

Tags: keyboard

I am using IntelliJ 2021.1 where the VCS menus has been renamed to "Git" and a Swiss French keyboard, the problem is that when I try to insert an "@" in my code I have to press `option + g` (the normal location of an @ on a keyboard of this type), which automatically also opens the "Git" menu...so I end with a typed "@" but also a menu opened without focus...

I have tried to look for the IntelliJ shortcuts but this one is not listed and the same is true for the Mac shortcuts.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Apparently there is no solution for the moment (they are discussing about it since 2017) [see here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165950?_ga=2.180277543.2010793253.1621496297-1578153985.1621496297)</strike>

With a lot of shame, I propose as a workaround to define a new live template in IntelliJ and use that one to type `@`. In my case, I type `anno + tab` and get the symbol without the git menu.

It is possible to disable the mnemonics for the menu and in this way `Option + G` does not open Git anymore. See [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010730200/comments/360003120220) for reference.